# Using PyQt5 to interact with HTML content in Android app

Tags: android, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

As the title says, I need a way to use PyQt5 to interact with HTML/JS web elements from within an app that should be deployed (also) to Android. I started looking at QWebEngine and QWebChannel and the result in terms of interaction is exactly what I need. Sadly, I realized that [QWebEngine is not supported by Qt for Android,](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html) and I am kind of stuck right now.

I've been reading that is somehow possible to use the deprecated QWebKit instead of QWebEngine, but:

1. One would need to compile PyQt with QWebKit (and I don't know how to do that)
2. I have no idea how to replace the functionality of QWebChannel (is this required or should I be able to use it along with QWebKit?)
3. I don't know if it worths the effort, given that QWebEngine is newer and possibly it will be supported in the (hopefully near?) future.

Last, I should add I don't know anything about QML and its interactions through PyQt, if this is important in this scenario.

Can anybody suggest if using QWebKit now is the way to go, or an alternative path to follow? Should I consider giving up using PyQt for my purpose at present?

**-- EDIT1 --**

I think I found something interesting regarding using [QtWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html).

> Qt WebView provides a way to display web content in a QML application
>   without necessarily including a full web browser stack by using native
>   APIs where it makes sense.
>
> This is useful on mobile platforms such as Android, iOS, and WinRT;
>   especially on iOS, where policy dictates that all web content is
>   displayed using the operating system's web view.

Unfortunately, this imples understanding a bit of QML and using [QQuickWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html) to embed the QML webview inside a widget (as suggested [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/65265/qwebengine-not-for-android)).

Does anybody have experience in using QtWebView with PyQt5 and can provide some suggestions? Would this be a reasonable path?